# Dynamics CRM 2016 Javascript forEach not supported

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

So I am trying to write javascript code for a ribbon button in  Dynamics CRM 2016 that will grab a phone number from a list of Leads that can be seen in the Active Leads window.

However, when I try to run it, I get an error telling me

[image]

As I step into my code (I'm debugging), I see this error

[image]

Here is the code I am working with.

```
   function updateSelected(SelectedControlSelectedItemIds, SelectedEntityTypeName) {
            // this should iterate through the list
            SelectedControlSelectedItemIds.forEach(
           function (selected, index) {
               //this should get the id and name of the selected lead 
               getPhoneNumber(selected, SelectedEntityTypeName);
           });

   }
    //I should have the lead ID and Name here, but it is returning null 
    function getPhoneNumber(id, entityName) {
       var query = "telephone1";
       Sdk.WebApi.retrieveRecord(id, entityName, query, "",
       function (result) {
           var telephone1 = result.telephone1;
           // I'm trying to capture the number and display it via alert.
          alert(telephone1);
       },
       function (error) {
           alert(error);
       })
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you did not mix up the parameters in Ribbon Workbench? I think that you simply have selected entity name as first parameter and selected ids as second parameter. It should be easy to debug - what type is SelectedControlSelectedItemIds?

Comment: I believe SelectedControlSelectedItemIds is a string.

Comment: If it's a string then you must have mixed up your parameters

Comment: Okay, so the CRM Parameter order in the work bench should be: SelectedControlSelectedItedIDs and PrimaryEntityTypeNeame?

Comment: Can't you simply debug the code and check what values are there? It's really basics of programming and not difficult at all... The questions that you are asking made me 100% sure that you did not put even one breakpoint to check what exactly happens in the code.

Comment: I put several debugger; statements in the code. The problem was, it would not even get the entity ID. It would consistently return null. I had one in the updateSelected function and the forEach function. I also had several in getPhone Number. The debugger is how I got the errors above.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an javascript error. In js you can only use forEach on an array. SelectedControlSelectedItemIds is an object not an array.

To loop though an object, you can do the following.

```js
for (var key in SelectedControlSelectedItemIds){
    if(SelectedControlSelectedItemIds.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        getPhoneNumber(SelectedControlSelectedItemIds[key], SelectedEntityTypeName)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I figured it out. I had help, so I refuse to take full credit.

First, I had to download the SDK.WEBAPI.

I then had to add the webAPI to my Javascript Actions in the Ribbon Tool Bench.

Then, I had to create a function to remove the brackets around the

```
SelectedControlSelectedItemIds
```

Firstly, I had to use the API WITH the forEach method in order for it to work.

These are the revisions to my code.

```
function removeBraces(str) {
    str = str.replace(/[{}]/g, "");
    return str;
}


function updateSelected(SelectedControlSelectedItemIds, SelectedEntityTypeName) {

//alert(SelectedEntityTypeName);
SelectedControlSelectedItemIds.forEach(
       function (selected, index) {

        getPhoneNumber(removeBraces(selected), SelectedEntityTypeName);
    //    alert(selected);
       });
}

function getPhoneNumber(id, entityName) {
   var query = "telephone1";
   SDK.WEBAPI.retrieveRecord(id, entityName, query, "",
   function (result) {
   var telephone1 = result.telephone1;
   formatted = telephone1.replace(/[- )(]/g,'');
   dialready = "1" + formatted;
   withcolon = dialready.replace(/(.{1})/g,"$1:")
   number = telephone1;      


    if (Xrm.Page.context.getUserName() == "Jerry Ryback") {
                    url = "http://111.222.333.444/cgi-bin/api-send_key";
                } else if(Xrm.Page.context.getUserName() == "Frank Jane") { 
                               url = "http://222.333.444.555/cgi-bin/api-send_key";
                            } 
                   else if( Xrm.Page.context.getUserName() == "Bob Gilfred"){
                               url = "http://333.444.555.666/cgi-bin/api-send_key";
                            }          
                   else if( Xrm.Page.context.getUserName() == "Cheryl Bradley"){
                                url = "http://444.555.666.777/cgi-bin/api-send_key";
                            }              
                   else if( Xrm.Page.context.getUserName() == "Bill Dunny"){
                               url = "http://555.666.777.888/cgi-bin/api-send_key";
                            }


 if (url != "") {
                    var params = "passcode=admin&keys=" + withcolon + "SEND";
                    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    http.open("GET", url + "?" + params, true);
                    http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                        if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                            alert(http.responseText);
                        }
                    }
                    http.send(null);
                }

},
   function (error) {
     //  alert(error);
   })


}
```

To elaborate, once I successfully get the number, I remove the parenthesis, dashes and white-space. Then, I add a "1" to the beginning. Finally, I insert colons in between each number. Then, I create an HTTP command and send it to the office phone of whoever is using CRM at the time. The user eval and HTTP message is my code. I'm showing you all of this because it was a great learning experience, and this feature really adds to the functionality.

I hope some of you find this useful.

Thanks for the help.